# Why can't Java Reflection find the package-private constructor of a class in another package?

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, nosuchmethod

I have the following API code, shortened for brevity:

```
public class Vec
{
    Vec(int x, int y, int z) {/*implementation*/}
    //other fields and methods irrelevant to question and not shown
}
```

Now, I'm trying to write code in a package different from that class above that uses reflection to invoke the constructor of that class and create a new instance of it. Here's what I've tried (code below is in my application's `main` method):

```
Constructor<Vec> c = Vec.class.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
c.setAccessible(true);
Vec newVec = c.newInstance(1, 2, 3);
```

However, when running the above code, I get an exception on the first line in the latter code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: somePackages.Vec.<init>(int, int, int)
```

Why is it still giving that exception, even if that constructor still exists? I'm running this code using `oracle-java8-jdk` on my Raspberry Pi, if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Class#getConstructor(Object...)` javadoc states

> Returns a `Constructor` object that reflects the specified `public`
>   constructor of the class represented by this `Class` object

Your constructor is not `public`. It has no access modifier and is therefore package private.

Use `getDeclaredConstructor(Object...)`.